# SQL count without grouping

Tags: sql

I have the following data which I want to write a query for:

```
Table1

A     B
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
3     1 
3     2
4     1
5     1 
5     2
5     3
```

I want to write a query which only returns data from A and B when the count of B (not the value) is greater than one but I don't want the grouping.  For example:

```
A     B
1     1
1     2
1     3
3     1 
3     2
5     1 
5     2
5     3
```

Notice 2 & 4 are missing as they only have count of exactly one in the B column.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Table1.A, Count(Table1.B) AS [Count of B]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.A
HAVING (((Count(Table1.[B]))>1))
ORDER BY A
```

however I am unable to get rid of the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that uses standard SQL:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where (select count(*) from table1 t2 where t2.a = t.a) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to hide the grouping in a subquery, so your main query doesn't get grouped:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  b IN (SELECT   b
             FROM     table1
             GROUP BY b
             HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.A IN 
(
  SELECT Table1.A
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Table1.A
  HAVING Count(Table1.B) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your B column have only distinct values (or you have some other row idwntifier), you can do your specific task without grouping:

```
select
    t.A, t.B
from Table1 as t
where
        exists (
            select *
            from Table1 as tt
            where tt.A = t.A and tt.B <> t.B
        )
```

As for more general answer - you can use window functions (if your RDBMS supports it)like

```
with cte as (
    select *, count(*) over(partition by A) as cnt
    from Table1
)
select A, B
from Table1
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

count() over, partition by will do the job

```
SELECT tbl1.*
  FROM (SELECT COUNT (1) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.B) cnt, tbl.*
          FROM Table1 tbl) tbl1
 WHERE tbl1.cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't completely get rid of the GROUP BY, but does it in a subquery so your results will be just as you would want them:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT A IN(
    SELECT A 
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY A
    HAVING COUNT(B) = 1
)
ORDER BY A
```